# C++ functions printing an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to code a small program and I want to print the array but it won't work, for the application, I am using a case function.

Build an interactive application that displays five options on screen:

Reading a string of numeric values;

- Show the String;
- Sorting the string using sorting by insertion;
- Sorting the string using sorting by selection;
- Sort string using sorting bubble sort;
- Exit from the application.

This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// int n[12] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15, 18, 57, 30, 20, 7};
int j, k, nr, n[20];

void values(void) {

  cout << "\n"
       << "input_values ";

  int n[20], nr, i;
  cout << "number of elements max 20 ";
  cin >> nr;
  for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    cout << "n[" << i << "] = ";
    cin >> n[i];
  }
}

void afisare(void) {

  cout << "\n"
       << "display array; ";

  for (int i = 0; i < nr; ++i)
    cout << n[i] << ",";
}
```

Comment: Consider using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and be more precise about the error that you are facing in your switch case.

Comment: You have two different arrays `n`. One global and one local (shadowing the global) in the `values` function. I suggest you stop using global variables, and pass the array and its size into the functions that needs them as arguments.

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: How do you use the array that was declared in the first function in the second one?

Comment: Also two different `nr` variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `function pointer` in this case, example:

```
void sort1(int*arr, int n);
void sort2(int*arr, int n);
void sort3(int*arr, int n);
void show(int*arr, int n);
//...
//implement body for the functions above
//...
int main()
{
   int arr[5]={5,4,6,3,9};
   int n=5;
   void (*funcPointer[4])(int*,int)={&sort1,&sort2,&sort3,&show};
   int choice=999;
   //assume you just type from -1 to 3.
   //-1 means exit
   while(choice!=-1)
   {
     cin>>choice;
     if(choice==-1) //exit
     {
        return 0;
     }
     else
     {
        funcPointer[choice](arr,n); 
     }
     //and do something what you want
   }
   return 0;
}
```

See more about `function pointer`
https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html